# Downloading a Model Derivative from BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I have a file hosted on BIM 360 with different versions. I retrieved the latest version's URN, translated to Base64 URL safe, and posted a model derivative job to translate to IFC. This URN does not have padding, but it does contain an underscore where the / character used to be. If I check the manifest of the version, it shows the derivative URN:

```
{
        "urn": <source_urn>,
        "derivatives":[
            ...
            {
                 "children": [{
                     "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file<source_urn>/output/Resource/IFC/rme_advanced_sample_project.ifc",
                     "role":"ifc","mime":"application/vnd.autodesk.cad",
                     "guid":<guid>,
                     "type":"resource","status":"success"
                  }],
                 "progress":"complete",
                 "outputType":"ifc",
                 "status":"success"
            }],
           "hasThumbnail":"true",
           "progress":"complete",
           "type":"manifest",
           "region":"US",
           "version":"1.0",
           "status":"success"
}
```

If I try to download the model using `<source_urn>` and
`urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file<source_urn>/output/Resource/IFC/rme_advanced_sample_project.ifc` (I converted it into a URI safe format using encodeURIComponent), I get the following error:

```
{
  statusCode: 400,
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
  statusBody: { diagnostic: 'The requested derivative urn is invalid.' }  
}
```

Comment: In the mean time, I tried converting to DWG and a DWG derivative doesn't show up under the manifest. Does that mean I'm using the wrong source URN? Forge says I was charged for the IFC conversion.

Comment: Forge says I was also charged for the DWG conversion despite it not showing up in the manifest for the source urn.

Comment: Hi R.Chen,
It's hard to debug and offer advise without seeing the URN details.
So maybe try this...   Try moving the RVT file hosted on BIM360, over to a standard Forge Bucket and perform the conversion from there... Use https://oss-manager.autodesk.io to help you try out the IFC export option and DWG option.

It sure sounds like the URN is not formed correctly, and using this tool, will help guide you in getting it right.  (perhaps the version is not appearing in the BIM360 encoded version  ?)

Comment: @michaelbeale The base64 source urn is dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLm1OZGRNN1J6UzllYW1rTlNwRFFNLVE_dmVyc2lvbj0y and the encoded derivative urn is urn%3Aadsk.viewing%3Afs.file%3AdXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLm1OZGRNN1J6UzllYW1rTlNwRFFNLVE_dmVyc2lvbj0y%2Foutput%2FResource%2FIFC%2Frme_advanced_sample_project.ifc . I figured the source urn was correct since the GET manifest worked, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: did the oss-manager help you?  can you try downloading the IFC via the OSS_manager tool I mentioned above ?

Comment: The tool seems to be broken for me. When I enter my client ID and secret it says they are invalid. I'm copying them directly from the Forge page.

Comment: Ok - that seems like a clue, that perhaps the forge account or forge App, is broken.  Can you try creating a new forge test account and forge app... and try OSS_manager tool again ?

Comment: Created a new forge account, same thing happens.